# How to model computations that depend on specific elements from a stream?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I am currently writing a program that analyzes files collected from multiple tar archives. I am using `conduit`, and the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/bartavelle/withdependencies). Here is a sample computation :

```
unixVersion :: Require T.Text BSL.ByteString UnixVersion
unixVersion =   (parseRedhat <$> requireText "/etc/redhat-release")
            <|> (parseSuse   <$> requireText "/etc/SuSE-release")
            <|> ....
```

The goal is that all these computations get "advanced" every time a relevant stream event is crossed (in the previous example, that would be the tar entries corresponding to `/etc/redhat-release` or `/etc/SuSE-release`).

A "full" example of the usage of such a function could be something like :

```
tarStream "/path/to/tar.gz" =$ withRequirement [listcve] fst snd
                            =$ CL.concat
                            $$ CL.consume
```

with

```
-- given the version of an OS and a list of installed packages, gives the CVEs
-- affecting this host.
listcve :: Require FilePath BSL.ByteString [CVE]
listcve = listCVEs <$> (cvelist <$> unixVersion)
                   <*> (T.lines <$> requireText "/soft/packages.lst")
    where
        listCVEs cvelist packages = ....
        cvelist v = case v of
                       REDHAT -> redhatCVEs
                       _      -> defaultCVEs
```

This contrived example only has a single computation, but my final program will have around 30, with several "shared" computations (like `unixVersion`). In order to implement this, I decided I needed a way to know if a given element of the stream was susceptible of being requested by one of these `Require` computation. This means I need a function like :

```
getRequirements :: Require a b c -> S.Set a
```

Unfortunately, this probably means the `Require a b` can at most be an `Applicative`, and will never be a `Monad`.

Then there is the `withRequirement` function that has type :

```
withRequirement :: (Ord identifier, Eq identifier, Monad m)
                => [Require identifier content x] -- ^ The list of dependent computations
                -> (a -> identifier)              -- ^ Extracting the identifier
                -> (a -> m content)               -- ^ Extracting the content, possibly with effects
                -> Conduit a m x
```

And that works like an interpreter for the list of requirements.

Anyway, here are my questions :

- How can I model these computations to achieve sharing ? The `unixVersion` analyzer for example is used by several other analyzers. In my current implementation, it's recomputed for each of them.
- Is there a way to have a `Monad` interface to this, yet not try to run every analyzer for each stream entry ?

Comment: It's not very clear what `Require` should be. Is it a parser? Or should it represent some kind of a stateful computation, as you talk about "advancing" them? Also what specifically would you like to share and between what? I tried to look at the github page, but it didn't help much. It feels that you might want to separate these things: Have an applicative parser that also knows the set of elements it needs, and then some kind of an interpreter that runs such a single parser on a stream(s) of events.

Comment: (Also note that linking to github makes the question non-self-contained - when you push another changes to the repo, the link won't reflect the state corresponding to the answer any more. Linking to a specific commit would be better, but still the project/accout can be deleted/renamed, so it's always better to extract a small, [self-contained](http://sscce.org/) piece of code and put it directly into the question.)

Comment: I tried to follow your recommendation. `Require` isn't a parser, it's just a tree like datatype that represents the computation. It's then evaluated by an interpreter-like function, as you suggest. It's also traversable by another function that returns the list of required identifiers.